# tcl8.4-dev dependency problems

Tags: 12.04, installation

I got a problem when installing gperf. It looks like this

```
"dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tcl8.4-dev:
 tcl8.4-dev depends on tcl8.4 (= 8.4.16-4ubuntu1); however:
  Version of tcl8.4 on system is 8.4.19-4ubuntu3.
dpkg: error processing tcl8.4-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: thank u for ur feedback! but it still doesn't wrok. the error message is the same as before.

Comment: did you remove tcl comeletely before the commands?!